# How to use encrypted web.config in ASP.NET MVC project to get connection string?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I encrypted my web.config file but when I upload the web.config into server the website is not accessible any more.

First I create a key by typing this code in cmd:

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp
```

Then I modify web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework" 
     type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
     EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
     requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
     <add name="MyProvider"
      type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, 
      System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
      processorArchitecture=MSIL"
      keyContainerName="MyKeys"
      useMachineContainer="true" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>

  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="sth" connectionString="Data Source=sth; Initial 
    Catalog=2888_AtiRayan; User ID=sth; Password=sth; Integrated 
    Security=False;"   
    providerName="System.Data.SQLClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Last I run below code in cmd and web.cofig encrypted successfully.

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "/MyApplication" -prov "MyProvider"
```

How do I use or decrypt this file?

All I found is decrypting by coding in cmd like above, but I uploaded my source to server and I can't access it so what can I do?

How can I use connection string from this encrypted file which is uploaded to server?